# How to get HTTP Status Code from Powershell Invoke-WebRequest call?

Tags: powershell

I'm running a Windows .bat file trying to execute a process via url. I'd like to extract the Http Status Code from this call. The examples I've found led me to this snippet which reports 200 just fine. But when I test with invalid url to get a 404, Http Status Code isn't set. Instead, error details are being displayed in the DOS prompt. Is there a way I can reliably extract Http Status Code, regardless of the status code series? If this snippet doesn't work, I'm open to other ideas. I just need to have that status code in the variable so I can continue my logic.

```
SET URL=https://stackoverflow.com

For /f "usebackqdelims=" %%A in (
  `Powershell.exe -nologo -NoProfile -command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri %URL% -UseBasicParsing | Select-Object -Expand StatusCode"`

) Do Set HTTP_STATUS_CODE=%%A

echo HTTP_STATUS_CODE=%HTTP_STATUS_CODE%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP 404 is treated as an error, so the command never returns anything.

Wrap the pipeline in a `try`/`catch` block and grab the status code from the thrown exception instead:

```
Powershell.exe -nologo -NoProfile -command "try{Invoke-WebRequest -Uri %URL% -UseBasicParsing -EA Stop | Select-Object -Expand StatusCode}catch{$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode}"
```

Comment: This seems to be working but it puts 'NotFound' into my variable and not 404. When I use a valid url, I get 200 in my variable. Is there a Response.StatusCodeNumber or something to that effect?

Comment: @jacekn put a `+` in front of `$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode`, then PowerShell will convert it to its underlying numerical value: `try{...}catch{+$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode}`

Comment: This `$_.exception.response.statuscode.value__` did it. Thanks!